# WebRtc SignalR Multiple user at a time one to many user

Tags: .net, signalr, webrtc

Is it possible to handle multiple user with signalr for webrtc (One to many user scenario)? If yes what are limitation for signalr as signalling service of webrtc? please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be using SignalR as your signaling server.

The **signaling is the discovery and negotiation process among peers, it is used to detect the peers and exchange information on how they can connect**: they end up exchanging Session descriptions to set up the media ports they will use to communicate. Now, WebRTC doesn't really care on how you set up this handshake, it doesn't define a standard protocol, so you can use SignalR, or WebSockets, or whatever mechanism it's easier for you, but you need to take care of it.
Now, once your peers have remote session descriptions set up, they can start the actual webrtc communication.

You can of course do multi-peer connections: **for each peer that you wanna connect to another peer, you'll need to do the signaling proces**s, otherwise they won't know how to connect with each other, and you will need, for each client, to keep track of who it is connected to, that is up to you, but it could be easy to save the RTCPeerConnection instances you have for each remote peer id. There is an example for multi-peer connections on [webrtc](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/multiple/), and the [source code](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/peerconnection/multiple/js/main.js).
You might wanna search also about **RTCMultiConnection**.

With all that said, I think SignalR is not going to be your bottleneck... but actually if you start having a peer broadcasting to too many peers.
**Have you considered using a media server like Kurento?** It'd make your life easier when broadcasting from one to many (check their [tutorials](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials.html#webrtc-one-to-many-broadcast)).

I hope this helps a little bit!